# Android Studio SDK Issue

Tags: android-studio, sdk

I was installed new version of Android Studio but its not show the SDK .Any one help to solve this path issue.See this images.

[Android studio configure that not show the SDk where i fix it path of sdk[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1D6p.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egItu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Generally the stored path of android sdk in generally hidden.
So as per my experiences go as i say,

1. First allow your Pc to show hidden file.
2. Go to the following directory of your Pc or Lappy:
   `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android`
3. Here You can see your Sdks.
4. Open Android Studio
5. Press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT
6. In search bar type "sdk" .(Beside it you will see the android sdk location.Change it.)
7. Set the path of android sdk which you went into earlier in your lappy's directory shown above.

Comment: Then Press File in android studio which you will find on the top bar of the window.                                  And then press settings

Comment: YA .this is why you have such error..  So browse in the directory to hidden folder of AppData inside Android folder and then into Sdk. Select that path directory and you are done. HAPPY CODING !!

Comment: Well then all you need to do is ,download all new sets of sdk from standalone manager into ur desired directory..This is last step you could do .

Comment: The selected directory is not valid home for jdk

Comment: Please send some link complete pkg of sdk or perfectible android studio

Answer (score 0):

http://filehippo.com/download_android_sdk/download/dd03cc329af0cd74b0e34afce1b4888e/

Here's the link..
And I ain't on Skype. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who give me suggestion.
Now its fix to reinstall complete android studio.
jdk file croup t or missing that why its show many problem.
I copy sdk file in another place and paste again when i reinstall my android studio its fix:) and no need to be download again sdk packages.